# Building 64bit libpython27.a using cygwin, dlltool

Tags: python, cygwin, mingw, cross-compiling, win64

I'm trying to build a python extension DLL on a 64bit Win7 machine using cygwin (as cygwin only run as 32bit process, this is actually cross-compiling).

I created libpython27.a myself from python27.dll using dlltool (as explained, for example, [here](http://wiki.cython.org/InstallingOnWindows)), but the build fail during the linker phase saying
  `skipping incompatible c:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a when searching for -lpython27`
This is exactly the error reported [here](http://groups.google.com/group/cython-users/browse_thread/thread/517ef4913afeeaf9) (where the guy ended up moving to MSVC compiler...).

More info:
- Active Python 2.7.2, win64, x64
- latest version of cygwin, using the /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe compiler

**Does anyone know if this is supported?

Is there way to use dlltool which I miss here?**

(I did found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/forums/forum/723797/topic/3882579) the guidance to use
`dlltool --as-flags=--64 -m i386:x86-64 -k -l libpython27.a -d python.def`
but when doing so I got `"invalid bfd target"` error from dlltool)

Thanks!

**Update**: I believe it can be done because [Enthought python](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php) contains such a file. I would like to create one for the more common distributions which don't contain it.

Comment: Well if we knew about the flag, it wouldn't be _secret_ now would it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using the 32 bit dlltool.  Probably in C:\MinGW\bin instead of C:\MinGW64\bin.  You can change your path, or run the 64 bit tool specifically as such:

```
C:\MinGW64\bin\dlltool -v --dllname python27.dll --def python27.def --output-lib libpython27.a
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how helpful you find this, but at the bottom of the page you linked to there's a link to [here](http://wiki.cython.org/64BitCythonExtensionsOnWindows) - Where it says:

> Do not use MinGW-w64. As you will notice, the MinGW import library for
>   Python (e.g. libpython27.a) is omitted from the AMD64 version of
>   Python. This is deliberate. **Do not try to make one using dlltool.**
>   There is no official MinGW-w64 release yet, it is still in "beta" and
>   considered unstable, although you can get a 64-bit build from e.g.
>   TDM-GCC. There have also been issues with the mingw runtime
>   conflicting with the MSVC runtime; this can happen from places you
>   don't expect, such as inside runtime libraries for g++ or gfortran. To
>   stay on the safe side, avoid MinGW-w64 for now.

Comment: Yes, I've seen it, not sure how reliable this data is. For example, in Enthought python libpython27.a is not omitted even in the AMD64 version.